# server not showing latest changes

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress website on Godaddy server. My changes not reflecting on page refresh. When I press CTRL + F5 then it shows latest changes. Problem is after login, it keeps on showing "login/signup" button but when I press CTRL + F5 then it starts showing me username with logout button. As per my RND, I have tried different ways like

tried following code in header.php

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

tried php code for this as well.

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

tried code in htaccess

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
```

But none of them is working. Any suggestion what could be the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's hard to give a solid answer to solve your issue but a few things you can try

Are you refreshing the page after logging in?
`header ('Location: <INSERT_PAGE_NAME>');`

Do you have static references?
If you have stactic files such as css or js files you can add `?v=0.0.1` to the end of it to force an update

`<script src="js/index.js?v=0.0.1"></script>`

Comment: Yes I was trying to figure out how to append dynamically version for each css and js file